# Try to install Adobe Acrobat DC: "ERROR: DW003: Third party payload installer Adobe Acrobat\Setup.exe failed with exit code: 1603"

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I am trying to update Adobe Acrobat DC through the Adobe Creative Cloud program. The update failed and I get error message:

> ERROR: DW003: Third party payload installer Adobe Acrobat\Setup.exe failed with exit code: 1603

What could the issue be should be?

[image]

[image]

Full error message:

```
Exit Code: 7
Please see specific errors below for troubleshooting. For example,  ERROR: DW003, DW071 ...


-------------------------------------- Summary --------------------------------------

 - 0 fatal error(s), 2 error(s) 



----------- Payload: Adobe Acrobat DC 18.11.20035.0 Adobe Acrobat\Setup.exe_18.011.20035 -----------

ERROR: DW071: 

ERROR: DW003: Third party payload installer Adobe Acrobat\Setup.exe failed with exit code: 1603

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Adobe Acrobat DC update program was conflicting with my previous Adobe Acrobat version (Adobe Acrobat XI Pro). Uninstalling Adobe Acrobat XI Pro did the trick. I had installed Adobe Acrobat XI Pro without going through the Adobe Creative Cloud program, maybe it contributed to the issue.